# The earliest discrete optimization problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, ho.history-overview, combinatorial-optimization

What is the earliest example of anything that could be considered a discrete optimization problem?  I can find plenty of examples of ancient continuous optimization problems (e.g. Dido's isoperimetric problem), but it looks like discrete optimization didn't exist until the 18th century as far as I can tell (Bridges of Königsberg?).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositiones_ad_Acuendos_Juvenes

Comment: See Philip Reiss, [A Mathematical Proof of Kinnim 3:2](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40914641) for some discrete optimization problems from the Mishnah (codification of Jewish law compiled in the early 3rd century).